# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined" error in bundle.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, browserify

I am trying to build a simple node.js app. node side is running fine but browser doesn't recognize the require function. To get around this, I am using Browserify. I installed Browserify and ran 'browserify index.js -o bundle.js' command. But when I run the browser side, I get ' Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined' error in bundle.js. The error is in following line of bundle.js.

```
var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
```

No matter what I try, I can't fix this so I am ready to give up. Any help will be appreciated.

My index.js is as follows:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();  
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const port = 3000;  //Set port to 3000. 
app.use( bodyParser.json() );  // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({  // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true})); 
app.use(cors());
```

In my index.html, I have following included.

```html
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: format the code properly, use a code block to write code.

Answer (score 0):

Browersify can transpile JavaScript to remove the need for the browser to support a module system although it can't "polyfill" libraries and frameworks that are available to NodeJS, eg. running an HTTP server as in your case using the `express` module. Those need a proper NodeJS runtime and can't run under a simple browser.

**Browsers are meant to connect to web servers, not be web servers themselves!**

Browsers' security restrictions will not allow a TCP port to be opened. My suggestion:  run the `express` server as a separate process on a Node.js runtime and use [Asynchronous JavaScript and XML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) **(AJAX)** to communicate with it.

Comment: Thanks but can you please give me a bit more detail? How do I run the express server as a separate process? js code on browser side will still not recognize the require function and what do I do about it? Lastly, is there any way you can give me a rough outline of how to use AJAX? Thanks.

Comment: I've linked the MDN introduction to AJAX in the answer, to run a seperate process you need to create a whole different instance and host it somewhere and your browser is very well recognising your require function with the help of browserify although isn't able to create an HTTP server, I request you to go through my answer again .

Comment: Thanks again. I am going through the MDN link re AJAX and I am trying to understand it because I am new. I am assuming that I will need to run my local server outside the browser as opposed to inside the index.js code via Express. I think I can do this by installing the Web Server for chrome tool from chrome web store or I can install http-server globally in npm. Can you tell me if I am on the right track or can you suggest anything else?

Comment: Or, I can continue using Express server but run it as a separate process but I don't know how to run it as a separate process and perhaps you can give me guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Correct that's what I'm saying you can continue using an express server **or** deploy an http-server globally via your method it works both ways! AJAX is just a medium to connect the hosted webserver **and** our seperate local server!